# Loading new page using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm relative new on javascript and have a problem with loading an .php page using javascript
I have a php form with 2 checkboxes. I want to check if at least on of them is checked and the goto the next page, otherwise stay on the current page.
All works except loading the new page from my website.
This is my code:

```
var webSite = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/reservations-" + "<?PHP echo $country; ?>" + ".php";
        if (cb_Checked == "Y") 
        {
            window.location.href = webSite;             
        }
        else
        {
            alert("No checkboxes checked.");
        }
```

For some strange reason it does NOT load a new page from my current website, however when I load a page from outsite my own website (ie http://www.boe.bla/test.php) it does work.
Is it a cache problem?

Comment: Are you sure that `webSite` is generating a URL that is correct?

Comment: I highly suggest using strictly equal like 95% of the time. so "===" rather than "==" they have different behaviors.

Comment: @Jacob 100% of the time would be a better choice.

Comment: Ahahaha thats fair. @CertainPerformance I try not to be too absolute but I have not found a case I "Needed" loosely equals so I agree overall.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying this syntax could remove issues and resolve your current one.

The strictly equals `===` checks the value and type.

The template literals (backticks) with the string can show possible spacing where you don't or do want it added into the URL more clearly. Concat is perfectly fine too though. I hope any of this helps.

```js
 const webSite = `${window.location.protocol}//${window.location.host}/reservations-<?PHP echo $country; ?>.php`
            if (cbChecked === "Y") 
            {
                window.location.href = webSite;             
            }
            else
            {
                alert("No checkboxes checked.");
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but still the same issue. 
After further investigation it was not the javascript itself but the way is was called.

I removed the call from the form itself and made the call by an input button. Now it's working correctly.

Comment: Happy to help and glad you figured it out :) , some of my suggestions particularly the strictly equals one is a best practice I strongly encourage using.